# Uploading file using apache httpclient

Tags: java, android, django

I am trying to write a program in android that uploads a file to server. I want to use apache httpclient for that.

Here is my code:

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.103:8080";
    File file = new File("/sdcard/alireza/ali.txt");
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"executing...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Do something with response...
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

The done toast doesn't appear.

Comment: You will get a much better idea of why the done toast do not appear if you actually log your errors instead of ignoring them.

Comment: I suggest to 1) look at you LogCat and paste it here 2) in the try/catch block use `e.printStackTrace();` to get the exception

Comment: I put that piece of code inside a async and it worked

Comment: @Alireza for the next questions, paste THE ENTIRE CODE, not a piece. This method probably wasn't working because you was trying to use it in the main thread, causing an exception.